# Java - Add Array Digits From File

Tags: java, arrays

I've got a problem where I need to read data from a file (sums.txt), which is full of lines that look like:
"204 435
22 31 12
999 483
28350 28345 39823 95689 234856 3482 55328"

I need to read each bit of numerical data as a token, break down each token into an array, and then add all tokens in each line together.
Specifically, however, it needs to be added like how humans do math.
Example:

```
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][1][3][2]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][0][0][4][9]
[0][0][0][0][0][0][6][3][4][1]
------------------------------
                        6,522
```

It adds 2+9+1 to get 12, drops the 2 down, carries the 1.. Old-school, very non-computer kind of adding.

I have no idea how to even approach it. I know I have to break down each one, but I don't understand the actual function of this process.

Notes:
-Some of the numbers are up to 25 digits in size, and BigDecimal and BigInt aren't allowed to be used.

Comment: Are you sure you have understood the task fully? Is this a beginners Java exercise?

Comment: It's in a beginning java class, yes. I understand basic java functionality, but it's the adding in "column form" that gets me.

Comment: The prompt is to test us to remove leaving zeroes, convert from strings to arrays, to read from a given file, and to process arrays. I can't say this is the most practical or useful program to test this, but it's what was assigned.

Comment: In you example, you align the digits to the right (as old-school adding does), but when you read in the tokens, it left-aligns in an array. So, does 2 = firstLineArray[0] or 2 = firstLineArray[lastIndex]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet would be to perform your operations in a different order. Correct me if I'm wrong, but what you're trying to do can be broken down into three goals:

1. Read in numbers from a file, line by line
2. Obtain the sum of all the numbers on a line
3. Convert all numbers read in into data structures where each digit exists as an array element

Stream the lines in one by one using a `Reader` class such as `BufferedReader`. Now obtain the sum of the numbers on each line, *before* breaking the numbers down into the new data structure.

Breaking down each token into an array of digits may be best achieved by creating a new object, which takes an integer and stores it within the object as an array of integers.

Comment: @Trokka Woops, just saw your comments, so you have been told to perform these operations in a specific order, have you?

Comment: The sum has to be obtained by adding each of the tokens together, after the tokens have been broken down into arrays to be accessed in a logical column format, meaning that this backwards way of approaching computer addition is how we have to get the sums; we can't add the lines all together using proper Java math.

Answer (score 0):

This must be some kind of homework problem...

The way I would approach it is similar to the way you've drawn it above.  Read a line from the file and then break the number up into ones, tens, hundreds etc by performing repeated mod / division by a power of 10 based on which column you are trying to calculate.  This will get you each digit into the array. For example with 6522 if you want to figure out what digit goes in the 100's place you would first do 6522 mod 1000 / 100 and you get 5. Similarly for any particular column.

Once you have all of your numbers split into arrays, you've got to iterate over each column from right to left.  Add the digits in the column and then keep track of a "carry" which you can calculate by dividing.

Your results would presumably be stored in a similar array which you can convert back to a real number by multiplying each column Y like: Yx * 10 ^ x, where x is the number of the column with Y0 being the rightmost column.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Definitely a homework problem.

To access, say, the hundreds of 6522 like you said, couldn't I break up each token and then read it character-by-character, such as reading the numeric value of a string, and only reading the 2nd character (or the x'st character in a for loop). My problem is that as far as code organization goes, I can't figure out how to write it in Java to transfer from a token to an array broken up like that and then add it all in that fashion.

However the carry variable is a huge help.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to hold your numbers in a 2-dimensional array, declared like:

```
 int[][] myArray = new int[height][width];
```

Then, you'll want to read them in, like this:
(for each number up to n...)

```
 String s = myTokenizer.nextToken();
 int temp = Integer.parseInt(s);
 int counter = 0;
 while(temp>0){
      myArray[n][width-i] = temp%10;
      i++;
      temp/=10;
 }
```

Then, you'll want to add them up.  First, declare a "counter" variable:

```
 int counter=0;
```

Then, start looping through each column, and for each column m:

```
 for(int i=0;i<height;i++){
      counter+=myArray[i][m];
 }
 myFinalArray[m] = counter%10;
 counter/=10;
```

And you're done, unless you are overflowing.

It appears that you want to work completely in strings.  Okay.

So, you can have `n` strings made entirely of digit characters, yes?

Let's put them into a string array.

```
String[] myNumbers = new String[n];
```

Now, we can proceed directly to addition.  For each string, we take a character from it at the same spot (in relation to the decimal point).  Then, since `char` can actually be added together like integers, we look at the ASCII table:  `0` is represented by value 48, `1` is represented by 49, and so on.  So we just subtract 48 from the `char` to get our equivalent `int`.  Using all of this:

```
 for(int place=0;;place++){
      for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
           if(myNumbers[n].length()>=i)
                count+=myNumbers[n].charAt(myNumbers[n].length()-i) - 48;
      }
      myFinalString = (String)(count%10) + myFinalString;
      count/=10;
 }
```

This should work for n smaller than, say, 10<sup>10</sup>.

Comment: This is really helpful. However, the tokens are up to 25 digits in size (9,223,372,036,854,775,807 is one of the numbers), and we aren't allowed to use BigDecimal or BigInteger. Maybe that's what I couldn't express as being the largest problem for me to grasp; how to take a number you can't access as a traditional number, and store it piece by piece in a 25-slotted array.

Comment: What other information can I provide or clarify to help? Asking for help here is really my only source of help on this one, the professor refuses to assist students in the lab.

Comment: Note that instead of going from right to left (the `-i` in the long line), we can flip the strings around and just go from left to right.  It would be easier to read that way, at least.

Comment: Also note that I neglected to add the logic to find when you're out of numbers to add.  This could be done by putting a boolean flag `hasDigitsLeft` on each string, and `OR`ing them all together to see if the outer loop goes more.